# Unable to upload brotli precompressed Json

Tags: c#, json, azure-storage, brotli

I have very little understanding of the c# streams.  I'm trying to upload brotli compressed json into azure storage.

```
private async Task UploadJSONAsync(BlobClient blob, object serializeObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializeObject);
  using (var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
  using (var destStream = new MemoryStream())
  using (var brotliStreamCompressor = new BrotliStream(destStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false))
  {
    sourceStream.CopyTo(brotliStreamCompressor);
    //brotliStreamCompressor.Close();  // Closes the stream, can't read from a closed stream.

    await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    await blob.UploadAsync(destStream, cancellationToken);

    //brotliStreamCompressor.Close();  // destStream has zero bytes
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure my lack of stream knowledge is preventing this from working.

Comment: Are you getting an error and if so what and where?

Comment: @MickyD did you not see the comments in the code?

Comment: All I can see is _commented-out_ code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the stream I had to set it position back to zero.

```
private async Task UploadJSONAsync(BlobClient blob, object serializeObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializeObject);
  using (var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
  using (var destStream = new MemoryStream())
  using (var brotliStreamCompressor = new BrotliStream(destStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false))
  {
    sourceStream.CopyTo(brotliStreamCompressor);
    brotliStreamCompressor.Close();  
    destStream.Position = 0;

    await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
    await blob.UploadAsync(destStream, cancellationToken);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to do `await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();`. It's an extra network call. `blob.UploadAsync()` will automatically overwrite an existing blob or create a new blob if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @GauravMantri [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClient_UploadAsync_System_IO_Stream_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) States otherwise, and is my experience: *The UploadAsync(Stream, CancellationToken) operation creates a new block blob or throws if the blob already exists.*.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You can use `BlockBlobClient` instead of `BlobClient`. From [`Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlockBlobClient_UploadAsync_System_IO_Stream_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobUploadOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_): *The UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken) operation overwrites the contents of the blob, creating a new block blob if none exists.*

Comment: @GauravMantri Also the same method (as I was just looking) without the CancellationToken does overwrite.  Yay Inconsistencies!!